# Jekyll thumbnail plugin with Liquid tag

Tags: ruby, jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I am trying to use a loop over a Data File with Jekyll. The code I have is as follows:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="12 columns">
    <ul class="clearing-thumbs" data-clearing>
      {% for photo in site.data.unusable_photos %}
        <li><a href="{{ photo.path }}" class="th"><img class="album-photo" data-caption="{{ photo.caption }}" src="{{ photo.thumb }}"></a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, it's getting hard to manually generate thumbnails for every photo I have. I found the Jekyll plugin [thumbnail](https://github.com/mrdanadams/jekyll-thumbnailer), but I don't know how to make it fit my needs.

The README shows this example: `{% thumbnail /path/to/local/image.png 50x50< %}`.

How can I use the `{{ photo.path }}` with the Jekyll plugin, so that I don't have to manually type filenames?

EDIT: Maybe I can edit the plugin so it can access the site variable?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I think putting photo.path would work...

Comment: @KevinChen Unfortunately I did not, though I think I had a workaround. Let me check.

Comment: @KevinChen You know what, I don't know. Sorry

Comment: If anyone else finds this, I made a modified version of thumbnailer that looks up the path as a variable if it does not exist on disk. The magic happens in the call to `look_up`. https://github.com/kevin1/jekyll-thumbnailer/blob/master/thumbnail.rb

Comment: Actually I'm going to make that into an answer

Answer (score 1):

I made a modified version of thumbnailer that looks up what you put as path as a variable if it does not exist on disk. The magic happens in the call to `look_up`.

```
def look_up(context, name)
  lookup = context

  name.split(".").each do |value|
    lookup = lookup[value]
  end

  lookup
end
```

Then in `render(context)`, call `look_up`:

```
source = look_up context, source unless File.readable?(source)
```

Full code: https://github.com/kevin1/jekyll-thumbnailer/blob/master/thumbnail.rb